# Are these 返り点 correct for this Sino-Japanese/Kanbun/漢文 order?

Tags: classical-japanese, kanbun

I was writing pseudo-漢文 as a fun exercise between a friend and me, and I found my sentence (What it is isn't particularly important. It was most certainly various degrees of ungrammatical) required the following order (Sorry about the inconvenient formatting)

```
　　1
　　8
　　9
　　10
　　5
　　2
　　4
　　3
　　6
　　7
```

I tried to put 返り点 in order to achieve this and ended up with

```
　　1
　下8
　 ｜
　　9
　 ｜
　　10
　二5
　　2
一レ4
　　3
　　6
　上7
```

However, I haven't seen ｜ used before to connect three characters like that, and when I tried asking a Japanese person they said it might be odd to. Neither of us are particular experts on 漢文, but it's true that although I think it's said it could be any number of characters more than one, I can't find any actual examples of 漢文 where ｜ is used to connect more than two characters. Is there something about maybe Classical Chinese, Classical Japanese, or 漢文 which might stop this from being necessary? Are the ハイフン okay there or is the order impossible?

Comment: I'm sure I have seen hyphen used, but I guess that's reasonable only if 8-9-10 constitutes a word. For example https://brain.vicolla.jp/2018/07/22/classical-chinese-bar/ (scroll down)

Comment: 収蔵愛惜 is connected with hyphens and treated as a four-character verb in one of two alternative ways to write it [here](https://kannbunn.blogspot.com/2017/08/blog-post.html?m=1). The other alternative suggests the use of 中 in your case.

Comment: It could be either 中8下9-10 or 中8-9下10, I think.